# Bulk commit in ember js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have `7k` amount of data and I am using `ember data`. I am using the following code:

```
cleanList.forEach(function(dncInfo) {
  let email = dncInfo.email;

  if (!email) {
    email = dncInfo.domain;
  }

  let type = (dncInfo.email) ? 'PERSON' : 'COMPANY';
  let donotcontactInfo = controller.store.createRecord('lead-generation/md-donotcontact', {
    "pattern": email,
    "type": type,
    "status": 'manual'
  });
  let promise = donotcontactInfo.save();

  uploadedList.push(promise);
  promise.then(function( /* info */ ) {
    // 
  });
});
```

When I use this with huge amounts of data like `7k`, I get the error 
`Error net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`, but if I use the same request for small data it works. What is the best way to handle huge amounts of data in  `EmberJs`? Is there any `Bulk commit` in `EmberJs` ?

Comment: What is the full stack trace for the error? Are you running this code locally? What does your backend look like?

Comment: @OrenHizkiya I am running it locally. It says Errorecnet::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error on after some number of successful post request.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over your items and saving each one at a time, do your modifications and store the results in an array. Then call `invoke.('save')` on the array. See the transition documentation for ember data at https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md that suggests this approach.